# Is there a "correct" general setting for the principle:  "tensoring any object with a projective object yields another projective"? 

Tags: rt.representation-theory, hopf-algebras, homological-algebra, reference-request

Apparently this principle was first formulated for left modules over the group algebra $A=kG$ of a finite group, where $k$ is a field of characteristic $p>0$ dividing $|G|$.  (See Exercise 2 on p. 426 of Curtis & Reiner, *Representation Theory of Finite Groups and Associative Algebras*, 1962.)  Here the Hopf algebra structure of *A* yields a natural left module structure on the tensor product of two left modules over *k*.

By the mid-1970s similar tensor product behavior was observed in other special cases for left *A*-modules and their tensor products, where *A* is a Hopf algebra over a commutative ring *k*:   (1)  the (finite dimensional) restricted enveloping algebra of a restricted Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ over a field of prime characteristic; (2) more generally  the hyperalgebra of a higher Frobenius kernel  when $\mathfrak{g}$ is the Lie algebra of a reductive algebraic group;  (3) the universal enveloping algebra of a Kac-Moody algebra in characteristic 0;  (4) the full hyperalgebra of a reductive algebraic group in prime characteristic (with "projective" replaced by "injective" as in J.C. Jantzen's book *Representations of Algebraic Groups*, I.3).    Relevant references:

B. Pareigis, *Kohomologie von p-Lie Algebren*, Math. Z. 104 (1968); Lemma 2.5

J.E. Humphreys, *Projective modules for SL(2,q)*, J. Algebra 25 (1973); Thms. 1, 2 (and note
added in proof referring to Pareigis)

J.E. Humphreys, *Ordinary and modular representations of Chevalley groups*, Springer
Lect. Notes in Math. 528 (1976); Appendix T (following Sweedler's suggestion)

H. Garland and J. Lepowsky, *Lie algebra homology and the Macdonald-Kac formulas*, Invent. Math. 34 (1976); 1.7 and Remark

J.E. Humphreys, *On the hyperalgebra of a semisimple algebraic group*, in *Contributions to Algebra*, Academic Press, 1977; 3.1

The arguments here typically involve special cases of a general theorem suggested by Sweedler (and closely related to the "tensor identity" discussed in a recent MO post [37709](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/37709/) ):   Let $A$ be a Hopf algebra (with antipode) over a commutative ring $k$, with Hopf subalgebra $B$ (possibly *k*).   Given an $A$-module  $M$ and a $B$-module $N$,  there is a natural  $A$-module isomorphism:
$$(A \otimes_B N) \otimes_k M \cong A \otimes_B (N \otimes_k M)$$  On the left side, *A* acts via comultiplication, while on the right it acts on the first factor.

> Is this the optimal generality, and if so is there a textbook reference?

Answer (score 5):

Dear Jim,

Perhaps this is the correct statement, which is proven in Etingof's lectures on tensor categories (though its proof follows from the yoga of tensor categories, as I'll explain):

http://www-math.mit.edu/~etingof/tenscat1.pdf

Proposition:
Let $P$ be a projective object in a multiring category C. If $X\in C$ has a right dual, then the object $P \otimes X$ is projective. Similarly, if $X \in C$ has a left dual, then the object $X \otimes P$ is projective.

Multi-ring categories are not so common, so let me specialize a little:

Let $P$ be a projective object in a tensor category $C$.  Then $P\otimes X$ is projective, for any $X\in C$.

The other things I mentioned are automatic in a tensor category.

The proof is that being projective means that the functor $Hom(P, -)$ is exact.  Since we have $Hom(P\otimes X,-) \cong Hom(P,-\otimes ^*X)$ (right dual), it means that $P\otimes X$ is exact whenever $P$ is (tensoring with an object is always exact).

Comment: strange, I edited to correct a typo, and it created a duplicate.  I'll check back in a second and delete the extra one, if it's still there.

Comment: ok, deleted the extra.

Comment: This is certainly the right way to approach some of the earlier examples and has become the standard proof of the tensoring-with-a-projective principle in a more limited case for the BGG category O (where it only makes sense in general to tensor with a finite dimensional module).  I'll have to look closer at how other work like that of Garland-Lepowsky fits into the picture.   Tensor categories clearly do provide a nice unified framework.

Comment: Yes, my answer was rather naive =].

Comment: It's not really naive, but I wonder about how restrictive tensor categories are for situations like Kac-Moody theory as well as for the somewhat dual but similar results on injectives for group schemes.   For instance, I hope to minimize finiteness conditions.